# Erro no deploy de aplicação Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, deploy, flask, apache

Estou tentando realizar o deploy de uma aplicação flask da mesma maneira que faço quando estou a utilizar python2.7, mas neste caso estou utilizando python3 e é retornado um erro no wsgi. Abaixo segue a primeira linha do traceback do apache2.

```
[Thu Dec 06 23:01:04.823744 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21968:tid 139980181575424] [client 189.127.245.17:55892] mod_wsgi (pid=21968): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

Instalei os packages necessário corretamente, inclusive o `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` que acredito ser o correto para Python3.

**FlaskApp.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ip-do-servidor
  ServerAdmin admin-do-servidor
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
  <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
  <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
```

Comment: Verifique qual a versão padrão do Python no sistema, ele pode estar carregando por padrão a versão 2.7 ao invés da 3.x.

Comment: Está utilizando a versão correta, python3.6

Comment: Para o Python3.6+ você precisa usar o `mod_wsgi_python3.6.so`. Se precisar de ajuda para configurar dá uma olhada [nisso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344252/how-to-install-configure-mod-wsgi-for-py3)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, o erro era no meu aplicativo e não no wsgi em si, consegui visualizar o erro correto após descer até a última linha do error.log do apache.